# Extra word in help document

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

I had cause to post text from https://serverfault.com/help/closed-questions in a comment today, and there's a section that reads

> too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or
>   has many of valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format

You'll notice an extra `of` between `many` and `valid`.  If someone with privilege could remove that, it'd probably be good.

Comment: It even would be many of good.

Comment: ...and this appears to be one of the pages we can't edit -- If nobody notices by Monday I'll bug the community folks in TL to fix their atrocious baby-killing grammar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo has been fixed; thanks for reporting it.

Comment: No worries, and thanks for the fix.